# Sort data according to years in column 4

Tags: linux, sorting, gawk

My data looks as follows:

```
1 3 4 2016 2 bam
2 0 0 1998 2 bbm
3 0 0 1900 2 bcm
4 3 0 2000 1 bdm
```

I would like it to be as follows:

```
1 0 0 1900 2 bcm
2 0 0 1998 2 bbm
3 3 0 2000 1 bdm
4 3 4 2016 2 bam
```

I tried `sort -n -k4` it doesn't give me what I want, is there any other command I can use?

Comment: Format your data in your question properly so that it becomes understandable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like columns 1 and 4 in your output are sorted independently. It can't be done with sort that way.
But if you are interested in sorting by 4th column specify field separator with `-t`

```
sort -k4,4n -t ' '
```

In case you want to additionally sort by other columns e.g. numerically by 4th, then alphabetically by 5th and then numerically by 1st just add them with `-k`

```
sort -k4,4n -k5,5 -k1,1n -t ' '
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not very clear about my first column, it is number 1-n and i want the line of the earliest birth year to appear as my number 1